# Why am I receiving the error: "must be caught or declared thrown java"?

Tags: java, exception

My current code:

```
class ThrowDemo
{
    static void throwMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside throwMethod");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            throwMethod();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Upto my knowledge exception thrown by `throwMethod` must be caught. But why does `IllegalAccessException` get thrown by `throwMethod` not caught by the catch?

Comment: Is this code Java?

Comment: @FrankerZ question was asked in MCQ form

Comment: But this appears to be directly related to Java. If this is not the case, feel free to remove the Java tag I added to your post

Comment: i think code is wrong.We cant "throw" an exception without try and catch block.